# send image and text as email with php

Tags: php

I have the following php email contact form, I want to make it possible for the users to include an image which would be sent together with the other text. for example instead of the first_name thing to have an image. thanks in advance!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "youremail@someone.com";
    $email_subject = "yourSubject";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>


Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send the image as an attachment or would you like to construct an html email that includes the image?

Comment: Do you want the image to be attached or displayed? If you want it displayed you need to send the email in HTML format. Regardless, sending email from PHP is a problem that is already well solved: [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) - no sense in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: as an atachment. i know it is solved but i need to connect it with that form and i dont know how

Comment: @MensurKosumi - Give it a try using any of DaveRandom's suggestions.  To help you learn this more easily, try constructing a simpler test case than your actual form.  Just a simple bare-bones PHP script that attaches some text and a file.  Then replace the parts of the bare-bones test, piece by piece, so that you understand how each change affects your result.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make an html email.

Add: `$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";`

And then use a standard img tag for your image

`<img src="your_url />"`

Comment: i want it as attachment, i've seen solved solutions but i dont know how to include it on that form

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my answer then.  I'll leave it here for anyone looking in the future though.

Comment: @ robbieAreBest, it ok thnx for try!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for I believe. Please see section with the heading "Sending Email with Attachment"
http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php